# Where Operator In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I need to use where operator to check some ids in my table as the following

```
 $subScIDs  = SubjectSchedule::where('subject_start_id',Input::get('substID'))
                        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                        ->select('id')->get(); 
 $subScIDsArray = array() ;

 foreach ($subScIDs as $id) 
 {
   $subScIDsArray [] = $id->id ;
 }
 // here my issue
 $subScInStudAttends = StudentAttendees::whereIn('subject_schedule_id',$subScIDsArray)
                                       ->select('subject_schedule_id')->get(); 


 if ($subScInStudAttends) 
  {
         return " true " . $subScInStudAttends;

 }else{
         return "false";
    }
```

My issue in this code

```
 $subScInStudAttends =  StudentAttendees::whereIn('subject_schedule_id',$subScIDsArray)
                                         ->select('subject_schedule_id')->get();
```

whereIn working well it fetch any id in `$subScIDsArray`, but i need to check each id of ids if **one** id in  `$subScIDsArray` not equal  `subject_schedule_id`' return false ;

How I Can do it ?
Any Suggestions ?

Comment: You mean you want to get subject_schedule_ids that exclude from subScIDsArray ??

Comment: No i need to check if subject_schedule_ids in StudentAttendess equal the ids in subScIDsArray  for example 
subScIDsArray = (55,43,2) , but subject_schedule_ids in StudentAttendess contains (55,2) return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length of the array that contains the ids against the length of the records returned.

```
if( count($subScIDsArray) == count($subScInStudAttends) ){
    // all IDs in the array have a corresponding record in the database
}
```

Or better, if your application logic permits it, simply get the count of the records and then compare with the length of the ids array.

```
$subScInStudAttendsCount = StudentAttendees::whereIn('subject_schedule_id', $subScIDsArray)->count('subject_schedule_id');

if( count($subScIDsArray) == $subScInStudAttendsCount ){
    // all IDs in the array have a corresponding record in the database
}
```

This code assumes the ids in your database are all unique.